# Angular 6 - strategy for autocompleting/dropdown display

Tags: angular, rest, http, angular6

### Angular 6 - autocompleting:

In my angular 6 app, I would like to implement an "autocompleting" form ([example](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples)). As I can not load some 6000 entities, I display only the top 5 matches from my database.

My issue is that as users add characters to the < input type="text">, the app's data binding will trigger an "update" to the list of top 5 choices. This means that the app will have to deal with multiple http requests which only the latest one might finish in time to be displayed. What is the best strategy for this?

### Things to consider:

- Trying not to waste back-end resources with unused requests
- Usage needs to feel fluid
- Could preload 100 entities in memory and update as input field fills. Is this good practice?
- Inspiration Facebook/Google search bar suggestion dropdown.

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#http